# Download webpage frame source within https

Tags: c#, asp.net, https, frame

May I know how do I download, or load into text to see the webpage's frame source which is within https?

Answer (score 1):

Its just same as downloading any file.

Download the parent page first. Use DOM or XML to get the `src` attribute of the frame. The download the content from source as well.

Here is a [DOM tutorial](http://progzoo.net/wiki/C#%3aNavigating_over_DOM_Tutorial) for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am a beginner in this. So, I actually manage to get the source for the whole https' html source. But within it, it's using a frame, I do not know how to use DOM or XML to get the src attribute.

Comment: Then you need to learn DOM. And learning XMl takes only 2 minutes.

Comment: Do you have any guides/help to guide me along this line? Thanks.. I'm really lost..

Comment: @user1321096 check [this](http://progzoo.net/wiki/C%23:Navigating_over_DOM_Tutorial) please.